# Is there any replacement instead of using CGI on python?

Tags: python, cgi

I am beginner with Python, so want more information about usage of CGI on Python, and is it need that I learn this lesson mean CGI.

Secondly what is another module or something else that is better than CGI which I can learn about it.

Thank You!

Comment: Python and CGI is not optimal. Maybe look at Flask https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.